# C# method syntax similar to object initializer

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

We have an extension method that accepts an action to initialize an object.
Is there some way to improve the syntax of such a call:

```
public static T NewRow<T>(this IUow uow, Action<T> action();

// this does internally call
public T NewRow<T>(Action<T> initializer) where T : IBo
{
    T bo = NewRow<T>();
    initializer.Invoke(bo);
    return bo;
}

uow.NewRow<ICustomer>(customer => { 
        customer.Name = "Zzz";
        customer.Info = "Abc"
);
```

I thought maybe I could use something similar to the object initializer syntax?

```
uow.NewRow<ICustomer>({ 
      Name: "Zzz",
      Info: "Abc"
});
```

The idea is to get rid of `customer.* = ...` in every line.

I would be happy for any tip.

INFO:

- We are using the latest C# language version
- The solution should support IntelliSense (e.g., Name and Info should be proposed to the user)

**Edit:**

- I can't use a constructor because I only have an interface. No class/implementation. The framework behind creates the object to the given interface `T bo = NewRow<T>();`. Which actual object gets created is decided by the framework
- Also initializers like `{ Name: myOtherVariable.FirstName }` should be possible

Comment: Use a `Func<T>` and have something like `() => new Customer { Name: "zzz", Info: "Abc" }`?

Comment: Use constructor instead?

Comment: `Name: "Zzz",` here you are hardcoding the value. maybe your real use case is using values from somewhere else?

Comment: an `Action` could be *everything*, not just a simple assignment. So if a client chosed to make a function-call instead, there literally is nothing to shortcut here. So no, what you want isn't possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an `Action` could be *everything*, not just a simple assignment. So if a client chosed to make a function-call instead, there literally is nothing to shortcut here. See this for example:

```
uow.NewRow<IWhatever>(() => Console.WriteLine("tataaaa"););
```

So no, what you want isn't possible.

However you could create some kind of `EventsArgs` that hold your names and use those within your `NewRow`-method. There's no need for an action if all those callbacks should actually be just assignement-calls alltogether.

```
uow.NewRow<ICustomer>(new MyArgs { 
    Name = "Zzz",
    Info = "Abc"
});
```

And within `NewRow`:

```
public T NewRow<T>(MyArgs args) where T : IBo 
{
    customer.Name = args.Name;
    customer.Info = args.Info;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The problem is that ICustomer can be any type containing any number of different properties.
So it is not possible to create a `MyArgs` type.

But I will think about it and maybe I can use code generators to create such a function for each Type T : IBo that I can find in my solution.

Comment: @ManuelKroiß if all those types have different properties, a common `ICustomer`-interface is pretty pointless, and a client has no chance to set the properties, as it only knows that interface. Either your types all have something in common, or they don't, in which case an interface is pointless.

Comment: Not really. They have something in Common. E.g. ModificationDate and ModificationUser.

Nevertheless, those are internal framework specific questions that do not belong to the 
original question.
I think you already answered my question. What I want to achieve is propably not possible. Thank you.